# SearchView taking all the space in the new ActionBarCompat

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I switched from ActionBarSherlock to ActionBarCompat (support library v7). After some adjustments, almost everything is working fine by now.

But I'm in trouble with the SearchView in the ActionBar. When it's expanded (actually, It's always expanded in my Activity), it takes up all the space and doesn't respect the space of other Action Items that are set to show always (showAsAction="always").

To simulate the problem, use this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_buscar"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/buscar"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/tentar_novamente"
          android:title="@string/tentar_novamente"
          android:icon="@drawable/acao_tentar_novamente"
          app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

In the Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.busca_action_menu, menu);

    searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_buscar);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);

    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setQueryHint(stringBusqueArtistasMusicasEAlbuns);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

This is the result in the android 4.3:

[image]

And this is the result in the android 2.3 (the action items doesn't even appear):

[image]

The same problem happens when I use:

```
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

The progress indicator appears very strange in the Android 4.3 and doesn't appear in Android 2.3.

The same code worked as expected with ActionBarSherlock. When there was some action item, the SearchView used to decrease its width to give space for the action items.

UPDATE:

I've posted an issue in the Android's Bug Tracker:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58251&thanks=58251&ts=1375191632

If you have the same problem, please follow the issue.

UPDATE:

I've tried to put the action items before the SearchView and this way they items appear.

[image]

But, the setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true) is still not showing the progress bar.

Comment: Dude, sorry for being a grammar Nazi, but it's "Álbumes"

Comment: @LuisLavieri, It's not spanish, it's portuguese.

Comment: My bad! Wow, it is so similar.

Answer (score 5):

This is definitely a bug about Android but a workaround can be including SearchView programmatically like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    getActionBar().setCustomView(searchView);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

You can also use a layout XML to define SearchView properties.
However "iconifiedByDefault" in XML tends to be ineffective in my experience. (This may my bad though)

Thanks for creating an issue about this.
Here's the URL to the related bug report:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58251

Despite what is mentioned in the bug report, my experience was the same with both ActionBarSherlock and ActionBarCompat. So I expect that ActionBarSherlock users are also affected.

Comment: Thanks man! It's definitely bug in "real" ActionBar not ActionBarCompat only.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `collapseActionView()`?

I use it like this:

```
public static MenuItem msearchMenuItem;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
           (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));



    msearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

    return true;
}
public static MenuItem getSearchMenuItem() {
    return msearchMenuItem;
}

public void doSomething(){
    //Collapse the SearchBar
    getSearchMenuItem().collapseActionView();
}
```

I don't know if it works with v7, but it certainly works with v4.

Try changing android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:title="@string/search_title"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
      android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the unique purpose of my screen is searching, so I want the SearchView to be visible all the time. And my code was working before V7, the problem is with the V7. I just would like to have a workaround for this bug until the Google releases the next version with this bug fixed.

Comment: I don't understand. Wouldn't you prefer to have access to other icons while you are not searching? Or you want to have it expanded all the time?

Comment: With ActionBarSherlock, even with the SearchView expanded, I was able to access the action items. Anyway, putting the action items first, I'm able to see them with the ActionBarCompat. My main problem now is that the progress bar is not showing with the ActionBarCompat. It was showing normally with the ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: What if you collapse it after executing the query? What happens to the progress bar?

Comment: It'll show. The problem happens when the SearchView is expanded. But, in my case, I need to have the SearchView expanded all the time, since this screen is just used for searching. I only show other action items if I have some network error and I want to give the user the option to try again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

Or you can explicitly call the method with `true` as the argument.

Comment: As I said earlier, I want my SearchView to be visible all the time. So, your solution won't work.