# Android action bar overflow menu not displayed in portrait mode

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a standard Android action bar (I'm not using the compatibility library) with a SearchView and a handful of text-only menu items. I'd like to have the SearchView always expanded and the remaining items in the overflow menu. The code I have so far works fine on a tablet and on my Nexus 5 in landscape mode, but when the phone is in portrait mode, the overflow menu isn't displayed. If I add the `collapseActionView` attribute to the SearchView, the overflow menu is properly displayed, but I'd like to keep the search widget fully expanded.

Here's the XML for my options menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
          android:title="@string/search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_clear_history"
          android:title="@string/action_clear_history"
          android:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_feedback"
          android:title="@string/action_feedback"
          android:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_about"
          android:title="@string/action_about"
          android:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

And here's my `onCreateOptionsMenu` code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Here's a screenshot of landscape mode, working as intended:

[image: Landscape mode]

And here's portrait mode, with the overflow menu missing:

[image: Portrait mode]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: how about using the split ActionBar (splitActionBarWhenNarrow)?  This should get you back an overflow menu in portrait

Comment: Thanks. That does give me an overflow menu, albeit in the bottom action bar. I was hoping to keep everything in the top action bar, with the search widget resized to fit alongside the application icon and the overflow menu icon, as it is if you expand an iconified search widget. But that might be a misguided goal; it looks like all of Google's own apps iconify the search widget, and trying to fit an expanded search widget alongside other icons would probably cause problems. But I'm still curious as to whether it can be done!

Comment: splitActionBarWhenNarrow is a particularly good option if you want one or more of your overflow actions to be showAsActionIfRoom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
          android:title="@string/search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
    <item
          android:id="@+id/menu_item_more"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_overflow"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:title="CLICK FOR MORE OPTIONS">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/action_clear_history"
                  android:title="@string/action_clear_history"
                  android:showAsAction="never"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/action_feedback"
                  android:title="@string/action_feedback"
                  android:showAsAction="never"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/action_about"
                  android:title="@string/action_about"
                  android:showAsAction="never"/>
        </menu>
    </item>    
</menu>
```

I've added an `item` which holds a reference to overflow sub menu you can try this, if wanted, or can ask doubt about it. and `ic_overflow` icon could be [image: THIS]

Comment: Thanks. That approach would definitely work. I'm curious as to whether there's any way around this without resorting to creating your own menu, though.

Comment: @Ben thanks for giving bounty coz this is the first one for me, and i'll try to figure out what you stated in previous comment, and will post answer if found any.

Comment: No problem! I'm not sure there's any way around this issue other than using the method you described. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, usefull SO I have found was this : [SearchView taking all the space in the new ActionBarCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898282/searchview-taking-all-the-space-in-the-new-actionbarcompat), so the solution is to add SearchView manually from code, and not from you menu layout.

here is some code I am using with success on api 19 in portrait, in fragment with support actionbar:

```
public void initSearchView() {
    searchView = new SearchView(getActionBarHelper().getThemedContext());
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT
        | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    searchView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

   getActionBarHelper().setCustomView(searchView);
   getActionBarHelper().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

   searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(mOnQueryTextListener);
   searchView.clearFocus();
   searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
}

  protected ActionBar getActionBarHelper() {
    return ((ActivityBase) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
  }
```

I call initSearchView in onCreateView(),

Answer (score -1):

try

```
try {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
    Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class
            .getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
    if (menuKeyField != null) {
        menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
        menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't fix it, unfortunately. This phone doesn't have a Menu button, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Don't ever try and do this, as mansoulx mentioned, its an ugly hack