# can i use overflow menu and simple(traditional) menu in same app?

Tags: android, menu

I am new to android. **can i use overflow menu and simple(traditional) menu in app?**. **how?**
I also read **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492791/how-do-i-show-overflow-menu-items-to-action-bar-in-android)**, but this answer increase confusion.  In some device menu hardware button not found. So, i think that both type menu use is better than ovrflow menu confusion.

I just want to use overflow menu like, we click on a overflow_icon, it open 4 menu items.

Thanks.

Comment: sorry for bad English

Comment: See this ques and answer(not my answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819289/android-action-bar-overflow-menu-not-displayed-in-portrait-mode/20819334#20819334 it would be helpful.And yes u can.

Comment: thank you keshav. i see this answer, but my question is different.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like,

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
          android:title="@string/search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
    <item
          android:id="@+id/menu_item_more"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_overflow"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:title="CLICK FOR MORE OPTIONS">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/action_clear_history"
                  android:title="@string/action_clear_history"
                  android:showAsAction="never"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/action_feedback"
                  android:title="@string/action_feedback"
                  android:showAsAction="never"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/action_about"
                  android:title="@string/action_about"
                  android:showAsAction="never"/>
        </menu>
    </item>    
</menu>
```

I've added an `item` which holds a reference to overflow sub menu you can try this, if wanted, or can ask doubt about it. and `ic_overflow` icon could be [image: THIS]