# Implementing an Action Bar: ABSherlock or ABCompat?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

The application currently has *tabulations* and bar **custom made** (by previous guy) from fragments to copy cat Apple design.

I want to move toward Android action bar to provide Android experience and usual behavior.

**Should I implement Action Bar Sherlock or Action Bar Compat?**

Pro ABS:

- Lots of documentation
- Action bar Tabs is well known (that's what I need to do)
- About Holo theme? ABS is great to support it, how perform ABCompat?

Pro ABCompat:

- Supported by Google (better in the long run?)
- Better connection with navigation drawer (but I will not use one)
- No external dependencies in Java Build path

What others arguments help decide? **Which one should I pick ?**

From my point of view, provided I succeed to do a action bar with fixed tabs, the Action Bar compatibility is the best choice (but not by much).

Thank you for helping me!  (even providing arguments I missed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main reason that made me switch to ActionBarCompat is the Menu appearence in devices with android <= 2.3. With ActionBarSherlock, the menu appears very ugly, with the default menu of the device. With the ActionBarCompat, the menu appears the same way it appears when you open it in devices with Android >= 4.0 and hardware menu key.

But, be aware that the ActionBarCompat has some bugs to be resolved yet. I'm dealing with this bug:

[SearchView taking all the space in the new ActionBarCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898282/searchview-taking-all-the-space-in-the-new-actionbarcompat)

UPDATE:

Another bug:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58321&thanks=58321&ts=1375277660

UPDATE:

I've created a patched version of the ActionBarCompat to solve the issue with the ActionMode. See here:

[The ActionMode is being created twice with the ActionBarCompat r18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973528/the-actionmode-is-being-created-twice-with-the-actionbarcompat-r18/17973529#17973529)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information! 
I had already seen your bug issue (since I was looking for the first feedback on ABCompat)

Comment: I just found another bug. Well, my advice is: don't be an early adopter like me. Each day I find a new bug that breaks my app. The only reason I'm not coming back to ActionBarSherlock is the menu for old versions.

Comment: "don't be an early adopter", I have to implement an actionBar now (finishing the internship soon). In how much time the ABSherlock will start to show weakness due to low-support? Right now,  there is no true Action Bar in my application. Do u think I should let ActionBarCompat to mature and go for ABS, or since it is not about **migrating** it's better to go for the ABCompat?

Comment: Look, it was very easy to migrate to ActionBarCompat. There's not too much to modify when you're migrating. So, if you don't have problem with the way the menu appears for old Android and you don't want to fight against bugs, you should go with ActionBarSherlock and migrate in the future. I've posted some the problems I've had when migrating to ActionBarcompat here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17887573/1140713

Answer (score 6):

The reasons why I migrated my app from ABS to Action Bar Compat were as follows:

1. I have only a very basic implementation of action bar tabs and I could see it would be simple to migrate
2. I prefer the Google documentation - it is clearer and more complete
3. Software maintenance will be simpler and less error prone because I now have no external dependencies.
4. I had run into a problem with ABS whereby I wanted to handle an orientation change (but you can't because of the way ABS hooks in to Android).
5. I haven't seen any statements from anybody connected with ABS about their long term plans for ABS. So I'm not convinced they are going to continue to support it. I may be wrong - but I haven't seen anything.
6. Performance is not really an issue for me, but I can't see why Google's "native" implementation would run slower than ABS and I suspect that it may perform better.

These are just my personal impressions.

Comment: Thanks! Food for thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

I think that ActionBarSherlock was a brilliant piece of work, and a great service to Android developers. (By the way I don't have shares in Jake Wharton its developer.) Google have paid it the best compliment possible by including something that does essentially the same thing in essentially the same way (as far as I can tell) in the v7 support library.

But now that the functionality is officially supported some standard arguments apply as to which to choose.

ActionBarSherlock is a third party dependency, which represents a risk in terms of ongoing support. Unless it does something you really need that is not done by ActionBarCompat, or the latter has a bug which you can't work around or wait for a fix for, there's very little argument in favour of sticking with the former.

I recently migrated from ActionBarSherlock to ActionBarCompat and found only one or two minor issues, the main one being that a minor adjustment was required to the stock 9-patch images used for the action bar tab indicator backgrounds, in order to produce the standard tab behaviour on earlier android versions, in my case 2.2==API level 8==Froyo. (Specifically I adjusted the vertical stretchable regions so that they were not adjacent either to the top edge or the colored indicator bar at the bottom of the image.)

Comment: yup I totally agree on ActionBarSherlock.  I'll keep in mind your issues if I encounter similar ones.