# The ActionMode is being created twice with the ActionBarCompat r18

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I found this bug and I posted it in the Android's Bug Tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58321

I'm creating this Q&A-style question to help those who are having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same problem but you can't wait for this bug to be fixed, use the patched version I've created to solve this bug:

https://github.com/CyberEagle/SupportLibraryV7AppCompatPatched